# Focusing on flowering plants, are there reasonable explanations why pentaploids would be more fertile than triploids?

Tags: meiosis, mitosis, polyploidy

For the genus Rhododendron, triploids are sometimes fertile but pentaploids appear to be often fertile. Once Rhododendron seedlings gets above the triploid level, aneuploids not near euploid appear to become more viable at least in greenhouse situations. What mechanisms best explain this increase in fertility of odd ploidy and viability of aneuploids as ploidy levels increase?